# How to switch from GRUB to Windows Boot Selection?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

i'm on windows 7, and dual booting with Ubuntu 14.04.the thing is, to select OS, Ubuntu has defaulted me to GRUB, which in my opinion so much hassle because Ubuntu is just for fun and my work is done from Win7.how to switch from GRUB selection to the traditional Windows Boot Selection screen?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm concerned, if you get the Windows Bootloader instead of GRUB, you will not be able to dual-boot; you'll only be able to boot into Windows 7.  However, if you install Grub Customizer from within Ubuntu, then you can choose to make Windows 7 your default boot entry and every time the computer boots up you'll automatically boot into Windows.
To install Grub Customizer follow the instructions here:
[Grub Customizer](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-grub-customizer-in-ubuntu-13-04.html) or here:  [Updated Instructions for Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/grub-customizer)